# DNS name and IP address do not resolve the same

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

I have checked it at: http://www.ipchecking.com/ and they say they are the same. but when I visit each of them they are different

ec2-54-206-38-225.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com - 404 error Problem accessing /. Reason: Not Found

54.206.38.225 - returns apache default page

ec2-54-206-38-225.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/jenkins - jenkins launchs

54.206.38.225/jenkins - not found

My understanding was that the host name should resolve to the ip address and thus they shouldboth take me to the same place?

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably seeing is due to named based virtual hosts.

When your browser makes an HTTP request, it includes a header that says what host it is looking for. This allows a server to have more than 1 site hosted on a single IP address and port.

This can also allow a load balancer to redirect your traffic to different machines on its network for handling.

You can find more information at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: but I havent put a name with the request? the above ip address and host name are both what is supplied by aws.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
# curl -I -s http://ec2-54-206-38-225.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com | head -3
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 06:15:49 GMT
Server: Jetty(winstone-2.9)

# curl -I -s http://54.206.38.225 | head -3
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 06:16:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

# curl -I -s http://ec2-54-206-38-225.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com/jenkins | head -3
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 06:16:18 GMT
Server: Jetty(winstone-2.9)

# curl -I -s http://54.206.38.225/jenkins | head -3
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 06:16:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
```

From above commands (look at the HTTP response code closely),

1. When FQDN is used, the HTTP request is responded by JeTTy.
2. When IP Address is used, the HTTP request is responded by Apache.
3. Jetty is aware of `/jenkins` path
4. Apache is **not** aware of `/jenkins` path.

So this implies that, You have JeTTy acting as Reverse_Proxy/Load_Balancer. So the connection looks like this:

```
USER --> JeTTy --> Apache
```

Now, you need to figure out how JeTTy is configured for redirecting/denying  requests. [This](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler) link might be helpful.

However, Usually, I have seen that an application server is fronted by a web server as Reverse_Proxy/Load_Balancer. So, you might find that your setup looks like below:

```
USER --> Apache --> JeTTy
```

If this is the case then figure out how Apache is configured for redirecting/denying  requests.